# how to do pagination in this code?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

```
<?php
        include("config/connection.php");
        $qry="SELECT * FROM `students_info`";
        $qry_sel=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
            echo "<table border='2'>";
            echo"<tr>";
            echo "<td>SL_NO</td>";
            echo "<td>NAME</td>";
            echo "<td>ROLL</td>";
            echo "<td>COLLEGE_ID</td>";
            echo "<td>CLASS</td>";
            echo "<td>STATUS</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qry_sel))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                $slno=$row['sl_no'];
                echo "<td>".$row['sl_no']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['roll']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['clgid']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['class']."</td>";
                echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=$slno'>DELETE</a><a href='edit.php?id=$slno'>!!EDIT</a></td>";

                //echo"<td>"."<a href='delete.php?del=".$id."'>Delete</a>"."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo"</table>";



?>
```

Comment: did you even search for php pagination scripts ?

Comment: Never mind, I've given an answer below, hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I feel that there may be more to this question than you're telling us.

Comment: There's no pagination code in this. Do you think we guys are here only to write code for you

Answer (score 2):

The following steps will guide you on how to implement and incorporate pagination in your existing code.

- Go to https://github.com/rajdeeppaul/Pagination, download `pagination.php` file and include it into your project directory, like this:

  ```
  require_once('pagination.php');
  ```
- Create an instance of `Pagination` class, with appropriate driver, like this:

  ```
  $pg = new Pagination('mysqli', 'HOSTNAME', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE_NAME');
  ```

  Change `HOSTNAME`, `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD` and `DATABASE_NAME` as per your database credentials.
- Set pagination parameters using `setPaginationParameters()` method, like this,

  ```
  $pg->setPaginationParameters(10, 5);
  ```
- Call `getResult()` method of `Pagination` class to display rows based on the URL query `?page=X`, like this,

  ```
  $resultSet = $pg->getResult('SELECT * FROM students_info', NULL, $_GET, 'page');

  foreach($resultSet as $row){
      echo "<tr>";
          $slno=$row['sl_no'];
          echo "<td>".$row['sl_no']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['roll']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['clgid']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['class']."</td>";
          echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $slno . "'>DELETE</a><a href='edit.php?id=" . $slno . "'>!!EDIT</a></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
  }
  ```
- Finally, display pagination links using `getPaginationLinks()` method, like this,

  ```
  $pgLinks = $pg->getPaginationLinks();
  if(is_array($pgLinks) && count($pgLinks) && $pgLinks['prev']){
      /* previous pages are available */
      echo '&laquo; ';
  }
  if(is_array($pgLinks) && count($pgLinks) && count($pgLinks['links'])){
      /* show pagination links */
      foreach($pgLinks['links'] as $link){
          echo '<a href="yourPage.php?page='.$link.'">'.$link.'</a> ';
      }
  }
  if(is_array($pgLinks) && count($pgLinks) && $pgLinks['next']){
      /* next pages are available */
      echo '&raquo;';
  }
  ```

  **Note:** Don't forget to change `yourPage.php` with your page.

Here's **the complete** code:

```
<?php
    require_once('pagination.php');

    $pg = new Pagination('mysqli', 'HOSTNAME', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE_NAME');
    $pg->setPaginationParameters(10, 5);

    $resultSet = $pg->getResult('SELECT * FROM students_info', NULL, $_GET, 'page');

    echo "<table border='2'>";
        echo"<tr>";
        echo "<td>SL_NO</td>";
        echo "<td>NAME</td>";
        echo "<td>ROLL</td>";
        echo "<td>COLLEGE_ID</td>";
        echo "<td>CLASS</td>";
        echo "<td>STATUS</td>";

        echo "</tr>";
        foreach($resultSet as $row){
            echo "<tr>";
                $slno=$row['sl_no'];
                echo "<td>".$row['sl_no']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['roll']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['clgid']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['class']."</td>";
                echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $slno . "'>DELETE</a><a href='edit.php?id=" . $slno . "'>!!EDIT</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        $pgLinks = $pg->getPaginationLinks();
        echo "<tr style='text-align:center;'><td colspan='6'>"; 
        if(is_array($pgLinks) && count($pgLinks) && $pgLinks['prev']){
            /* previous pages are available */
            echo '&laquo; ';
        }
        if(is_array($pgLinks) && count($pgLinks) && count($pgLinks['links'])){
            /* show pagination links */
            foreach($pgLinks['links'] as $link){
                echo '<a href="yourPage.php?page='.$link.'">'.$link.'</a> ';
            }
        }
        if(is_array($pgLinks) && count($pgLinks) && $pgLinks['next']){
            /* next pages are available */
            echo '&raquo;';
        }
        echo "</td></tr>";
    echo"</table>";
?>
```

---

**Footnotes:** Go through the **Usage** documentation if you need any further clarification on the usage of this script.

Comment: What more can they ask for ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I believe the answer should not only be helpful for OP but also for future visitors. :-)

Comment: Yes indeed Rajdeep. Too bad the question got so many downvotes though. I'm pretty sure it's because there wasn't much effort put into it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Very true, a little bit of research would have given OP a good head start, but *sigh*

Comment: However and seeing the word "delete", am under the impression that the plot may be thicker than we think, and that they're probably wanting to be able to delete records. You may have been chased down a rabbit hole.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yep, *edit* and *delete* in the same line tells me that I should probably gear up for a *long* comment battle. :D

Comment: I didn't notice the "edit" part. I'm on mobile right now so scrolling is a bit limited (woah, watch for that deer!!!) lol. Well, I am doubting a long comment battle after their no response up there in comments. My general rule of thumb is; if it hasn't been solved within 10 comments, find your way out of the (rabbit) hole;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- *hmm*, good point! *Noted!* ;-)